# Approximation using a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

(Notice: I translated from german. Sorry if I made any mistake.)

Given is the Runge function: $f(x)=1/(1+x^2)$

We want to approximate this function on the interval [-5;5] with a polynomial $P_n(x) $of degree n.

We want this polynomial to approximate the function as good as possible in m evenly distributed points $x_i $in the interval and we write it as a linear « curve fitting » (german: lineares Ausgleichsproblem) of the form
$Ac = b$

where c represents the n+1 coefficients of the polynomial

Determine the matrix A and right side b.

My attempt: I don’t really see how to proceed. I don’t see what the matrix A should be.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Translation  between natural languages is not the problem, here, but you failed to translate it to "mathematician". What is "as good as possible in m evenly distributed points xi" supposed to mean? Least squares of sort?

Comment: We learned about the least square methode for approximation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let $P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$. The matrix arises from writing down the $m$ equations $P_n(x_i) = f(x_i)$ for $i=1\ldots m$, where the variable vector you want to solve for are the coefficients of $P_n$:

$$ \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}x_1^n & \cdots & x_1 & 1 \\ &\vdots&&\\x_m^n&\cdots&x_m &1 \end{bmatrix}}_{A}
\cdot \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} a_n\\\vdots\\a_1\\a_0\end{bmatrix} }_{c}
=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}f(x_1)\\\vdots\\f(x_m)\end{bmatrix}}_{b}$$

If $m\le n$ then this system will be solveable. If $m>n$ the goal in the Ausgleichsproblem is to find $c$ such that $\|Ac-b\|$ is minimal which boils down to solving $A^TAc = A^Tb$.

Answer (score 1):

**Important Addendum to the solution of @Hyperplane:**

We are faced here with a weird behavior of the approximation curve named the "Runge phenomenon" (see figure below). See (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon).

I agree with the equation

$$\tag{1}A^TAX=A^TY$$

given by @Hyperplane (least squares method) which is the classical approach for this kind of issue.

Let us take the case of 7 points $(x_k,f(x_k), \ x_k=-5,-10/3, \ -5/3,\ 0, \ 5/3, \ 10/3, \ 5$

("magenta" points on the graphic below). The approximating polynomial (in blue) passes through these 7 points, but between them, this approximation curve wiggles around the red (Runge) curve : we are very far from an approximation curve ! Furthermore, outside $(-5,5)$, it is even worse because the blue curve tends to $-\infty$ instead of $0$...

Remark : this phenomena will always occur when for example one wants to approximate a function with asymptotes like the Runge (or Cauchy) function.

[image]

Here is the Matlab script that makes the computations and plots the 2 curves:

> ```
> clear all;close all;hold on;
> f=@(x)(1./(1+x.^2));
> plot([-5,5],[0,0],'r');
> n=7;LS=linspace(-5,5,n);
> for K=1:n
>    for L=1:n
>       T(K,L)=LS(K)^(n-L);
>    end;
> end;
> C=(T'*T)\(T'*f(LS)');%least squares sol. of (T'*T)C=T'*B
> x=-5:0.01:5;
> plot(x,f(x),'r','linesmoothing','on','linewidth',2);
> plot(x,polyval(C,x),'b','linesmoothing','on','linewidth',2);
> scatter(LS,f(LS),75,'m','filled');
> ```